# React Highcharts with export functionality with 'react-highcharts'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts

In the codebase I work in, we have `react-highcharts` rather than `highcharts-react-official` and I am trying to enable highcharts export functionality.

I went to the react-highcharts doc and it says to use deprecated libraries - http://kirjs.github.io/react-highcharts/more.html

Does anyone know how I can use export functionality without using `highcharts-exporting` and `highcharts-more` since they are deprecated, with `react-highcharts` instead of `highcharts-react-official`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
// Import Highcharts
import Highcharts from "highcharts";

// Load Highcharts modules
require("highcharts/modules/exporting")(Highcharts);
```

Example with `highcharts-react-official`:

- https://codesandbox.io/s/4r57245nw7

Comment: I am unable to use `highcharts-react-official`, but rather `react-highcharts`

Comment: But have you tested those imports with `react-highcharts`?

Comment: Worked (using `highcharts-react-official`)! This method also works for other highchart functionalities. For example, if you want to download data as CSV from the menu, write `require("highcharts/modules/export-data")(Highcharts)`. The path appears to be the similar to the `src` attribute when including with `<script>` tags.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **Next js**, try this.

```
import Highcharts from 'highcharts'
import HighchartsExporting from 'highcharts/modules/exporting'
import HighchartsReact from 'highcharts-react-official'

if (typeof Highcharts === 'object') {
    HighchartsExporting(Highcharts)
}
```